# Some Instance Methods Are Undefined in acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am currently getting the following error on my post model which is under act_as_taggable_on for tags and channels.

```
undefined local variable or method `tag_list_on' for #
<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9864675b48>
```

I seems that rails cannot detect the existence of tag_list_on or set_tag_list_on methods; however, it does detect the tagged_with method, whose source is located in the exact same module as the other files.

RubyMine can detect the existence of all of these methods fine btw.

Here is the section of code that I'm performing all of these operations on.

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tags]).paginate(:page => params[:page]|| 1, :per_page => 20)
user_tags = @posts.tag_list_on(:tags)                                                         
custom_tags = user_tags - params[:tags]                                                       
@posts.set_tag_list_on(:customs, custom_tags)                                                 
@tags = @posts.tag_counts_on(:customs, :order => "count desc").limit(10)                      
@channels = @posts.tag_counts_on(:channels, :order => "count desc")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tagged_with`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb#L81) is a class method of `Post`, added by the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem.

`@posts` in your code is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not the `Post` class itself or any instance of it.

There is no `tag_list_on` instance method in `ActiveRecord::Relation`, hence the error.

`tagged_with` says it returns

> ...a scope of objects that are tagged with the specified tags.

[`tag_list_on`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb#L226) and [`set_tag_list_on`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb#L267) are **instance** methods of the `Post` class, added by the `acts_as_taggable` gem.

You need to call `tag_list_on` and `set_tag_list_on` for each **instance** of `@posts`

```
user_tags = []
@posts.each do |post|
  user_tags = user_tags + post.tag_list_on(:tags) 
end
custom_tags = user_tags.uniq - params[:tags]

# ...
```

Comment: Awesome, but tell me something though. Why do they only extend the use of some methods on ActiveRecord::Relation, but not all main methods that, one way or another, are probably going to be used pretty often together.

Comment: Also, how would you go about setting the tag list that was generated correctly? If I call set_tag_list_on for each instance of post and then call @posts.tag_counts_on(:customs, :order => "count desc").limit(10); I don't think I get correct behavior.